# JPanel's border make JLabel disappear

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

There is a frame. There a panel in that frame with BoxLayout. In that panel there is a ScrollPane. There is another panel in ScrollPane with SpringLayout. There is a label in that inner panel.

Here is a code:

```
package test;


import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SpringLayout;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


class MainPanel extends JPanel {    
    MainPanel() {        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        BoxLayout boxLayout = new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        panel.setLayout(boxLayout);

        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

        JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel();
        SpringLayout springLayout = new SpringLayout();
        innerPanel.setLayout(springLayout);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("test");            
        innerPanel.add(label);

        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, label, 5, SpringLayout.WEST, innerPanel);  
        springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, label, 5, SpringLayout.NORTH, innerPanel);  

        //innerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        innerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));

        panel.add(innerPanel);    

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);  
        this.add(scrollPane);
    }
}


class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    MainFrame() {        
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.add(new MainPanel());        

        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);   
    }
}


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {            
            @Override
            public void run() {                
                new MainFrame();                
            }
        });        
    }
}
```

Label "test" is visible as expected. But when I add a border to inner panel (uncomment the line, see below) the label is disappeare.

```
//innerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
```

Can someone explane why?

Comment: I think that the guilty is SpringLayout beacuse I tried to set FlowLayout as layout for innerPanel and Jlabel is showed.

Comment: I don't have enough time to analyse this, but I found a similar question (probably with a similar piece of code). I hope it'll help a bit: http://oracle.developer-works.com/article/5332647/Can%27t+add+border+to+SpringLayout+container+inside+BoxLayout+container

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
innerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
```

to

```
panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
```

I hope that's what you meant to do & it fixed your problem :)